# count over several List

Tags: python, list, count

I have many Python lists filled with words and among those words I would like to keep the ones who appears in at least two lists.

My first guess was to collapse all those list into a big one and then to keep the words who have a count > 1.

The problem is that I have some memory issue when I try to collapse all the list into a big one.

Any help please ? thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're counting things, use a counter!

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(['bob','steve','steve','joe'])

# c == Counter({'steve': 2, 'bob': 1, 'joe': 1})

c.update(['alan','jose','steve'])

# c == Counter({'steve': 3, 'jose': 1, 'bob': 1, 'joe': 1, 'alan': 1})
```

Comment: sorry i have spoken too fast, I still have a MemoryError when i loop over to upedate the Counter

Comment: @user2741700 your lists are probably taking up almost all of your memory by themselves.  Either convert each list into a Counter and delete the list, or use some other strategy (like just building a Counter in the first place, never using an intermediate list)

Comment: How many words do you have in those lists? I just tried this with a list containing 3248240 words and it worked fine and was really fast.

Comment: I think that the error is due to the too large number of element in the Counter. Thanks i will try to figure something else

Comment: @user2741700 I really, really doubt that, but okay.